# Get the root transaction using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a series of record. Based on the data below, how to get the root transaction (XR) where the **Doc Nos** is equivalent to **9600012264**

**Legend**

```
XR - is the lowest root transaction
XZ - is the highest root transaction
XA - can generate multiple times
```

**DATA**

```
Doc Nos      Type   TY    Amount     Cleared Doc
9500011864 | A121 | XR | 36247.62  | 9000001659 
9000001659 | A121 | XA |     1.00  | 9000001660 
9000001660 | A121 | XA | 36242.86  | 9600012264
9600012264 | A121 | XZ | -72490.48 | 9600012264
```

**CONDITION**

```
Doc Nos : 9600012264 
TY      : XZ
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
Doc Nos      Type   TY    Amount     Cleared Doc
9500011864 | A121 | XR | 36247.62  | 9000001659
```

Can SQL CTE Recursive is applicable on this approach. I am using SQL Server 2016?  Need help please. Can someone do the codes for me then I will improve it.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Not all products support cte's.)

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use CTE?  Surely a WHERE TY = 'XZ' and [Doc Nos] = @DocumentParameterID would do the trick?

Comment: If your DBMS supports recursive CTE this is the way to go.

Comment: I'm using MSSQL 2016 and I think cte is available on this version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursive CTE, note self-referencing in data. Hope no other cycles exist. Adjust data types if needed.

```
declare @DocNos varchar(20) = '9600012264';
declare @TY varchar(10) ='XZ';
with rc as (
    select *
    from Transactions t
    where [Doc Nos] = @DocNos and TY=@TY
    union all
    select t.* 
    from Transactions t
    join rc on t.[Cleared Doc] = rc.[Doc Nos] 
       -- stop at self ref
       and rc.[Doc Nos] != t.[Doc Nos]
       and rc.TY !='XR'
)
select *  
from rc
where TY='XR';
```